# Where do I start if I want to make music and audio for video games?

Tags: sound, audio, music, sound-effects, voice

I am a singer/songwriter/instrumentalist, as well as a video game lover. I have some basis in informatics but I have spent 1000x the time on music in comparison with programming. I came to think that making music and audio for video games could be a great way to make money while making something exciting. I dream of making my own game someday, and I thought that starting by making what I do best (music and audio) could make me discover the universe of game development, while giving me the opportunity to work on something that makes sense to me.

I can make many kinds of music and my vocal skills make it easier to create audio for games (beast sounds, animal sounds, human sounds, and so on). That said, I could tell this and that, but having credibility is very hard since no one knows how I sound. Where do I start? And how do I contact people that are seeking the kind of service that I offer?

I have almost 20 years of experience as a singer, 11 as a songwriter and 5 as an instrumentalist. I can use software to program audio performances, and I have professional quality microphone (Audio Technica 4050) and audio interface. I have all the equipment and the softwares (Pro Tools) necessary to record music and audio for video game.

Comment: I voted to close this as "how do I get started", even though that close reason doesn't apply directly.  Your question's topicality is...debatable.  The issue I see with it is that your question applies equally to absolutely every job you might apply for that involves producing audio, regardless of whether or not it targets games.  As a result, game developers have no extra insight about it.  As for the task of breaking-in to an industry, that's not game-specific either.  It's going to be tough to find useful answers on this SE.